# Should C/C++ packages run_depend on *_msgs packages?

Tags: ros, c++, package.xml, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While cleaning up MoveIt!'s build structure (https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/pull/305#issuecomment-230609078), I noticed that the packages run_depend on all the *_msgs packages they use. (std_msgs, geometry_msgs, sensor_msgs, ...)

To the best of my knowledge all these _msgs packages w.r.t. C++-only projects only consist of header files
that are not required at run-time. Should the run_depends be removed? Is it good/bad practice to have them in there?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238900/should-c/c++-packages-run_depend-on-*_msgs-packages?/) by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2950 on 2016-07-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In most cases, you should keep the run_depends on the message packages.

If you're building a ROS node in C++ that subscribes or publishes messages of a particular type, you should have a run_depend on that type so that it's available to debugging tools like rostopic that are written in python.

If you're building a C++ library that publishes or subscribes to messages, the same idea applies.

In either case, don't assume that another package will provide the dependency for you; that package may not need it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2016-07-06**:
There is no need to have "another package provide the dependency", because the binary/library itself simply does not *have* that dependency.
However, it does make sense to require the run_depend for generic python tools like rostopic!